# Build kotlin to apk with terminal

Tags: android, kotlin, terminal, android-build

i really want to know how to build kotlin to apk with terminal. Is it possible? if yes, how? this is source code i want to try
https://github.com/emedinaa/kotlin-mvvm/

Ref : https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676

This reference is about compiling java to apk, i still haven't tried tho. If compiling from java with terminal is possible, then i assume kotlin does possible too.